# I am having KEY ERROR in my cmd prompt while running twilio python api doc

Tags: python

I am apparently working on Twilio Chat doc and here is the error that I am getting

```
client = Client(os.environ["abc"], os.environ["xyz"], os.environ["wer"])
  File "C:\Users\hp\venv\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'abc'
```

I tried to do `key="abc"`, same error

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-python/commit/2ec02021e7df4503e7fcc9cd2e0cfe88a33d951d

This is the code link, from git

Comment: You don't have an env variable with key "abc"

Comment: You need to make sure your environment variables are set

Comment: Watch this:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8&list=PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU&index=56&t=0s

Answer (score 1):

Use a default value and if the key is not found your code will use the default value.See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.getenv

```
import os
DEFAULT_VALUE = 7
value = os.getenv('KEY_THAT_MIGHT_EXIST', DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client("x", "x")

message = client.messages.create(
    body="Machine 3 heeft aandacht nodig!",
    from_="+x",
    to="+x"
)

print(message.sid)
```

worked for me